# CustomView containing custom view recursion

Tags: android, android-layout, recursion, out-of-memory, android-custom-view

I have created a custom view (PlayListFragment). This component extends RelativeLayout and contains 1 imageView and 1 VideoView. I simulate a playlist functionality.

I want to add a new view inside my custom view (PlayListFragment) besides ImageView and VideoView. But this new view contains a PlayListFragment. So I want a "playlist" inside a "playlist".

I created a new custom view (TemplateView) which contains a PlayListFragment.

```
public class TemplateView extends RelativeLayout {

Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;
PlayListFragment p1;
PlayListFragment p2;

public TemplateView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}


 public void setTemplate(TemplateItem template) {

    this.removeAllViews();

    if("1".equals(template.getType())) {
        this.addView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.template_1, null));
        p1= (PlayListFragment)findViewById(R.id.template1_playListFragment_left);
        p1.setPlayList(template.getItems().get("p1"));
        p1.play();

    }else if("2".equals(template.getType())) {
        this.addView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.template_2, null));
        p2= (PlayListFragment)findViewById(R.id.template1_playListFragment_top);
        p2.setPlayList(template.getItems().get("p2"));
        p2.play();
    }
```

}

The PlayListFragment without the new view TemplateView is working perfectly, but when I add the TemplateView everything is crazy and I get memory leaks.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong or what could be optimized?

Thanks!

Comment: have you used inflater to add some layout to this custom view?

Comment: yes I use inflater, maybe is it the problem?